# Problem in revtex4-1 when a footnote ends with an equation

Tags: equations, footnotes, punctuation, revtex

RevTeX4-1 automatically ensures that a period appears at the end of each
footnote (or endnote). In most circumstances this causes no difficulty.
But when an endnote ends with an equation, RevTeX misses the period I
put in at the end of the equation, and it adds one of it's own on the
line below the equation. The result is *ugly* and *wrong*! Here's my
MWE.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,12pt,amsmath]{revtex4-1}
% I'm using the options aps, prl, and 12pt just to suppress
% some warnings; they do not affect the problem illustrated.

\begin{document}

This text includes an endnote that ends with an equation.%
~\footnote{Einstein derived the equation
  \[
    E = m c^2.
  \]
}

\end{document}
```

Help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Putting `\renewcommand{\bibitemNoStop}{}` in the preamble might work, but then you'd have to type all periods yourself rather than rely on revtex to add them.

Comment: A copy editor might argue that it's not only wrong ending a footnote with a displayed equation in a footnote, but having one in the first place.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the dot? It's a rather special case.

Comment: @Alex -- the problem is not that there are two dots, but that the one added automatically is on a separate line.  that's much harder to get rid of.

Comment: you might try localizing the redefinition suggested by @Dan by inserting an open brace followed by the `\renewcommand...` just before the footnote, and a matching closing brace after the footnote.  just watch out not to add unwanted spaces in the output.

Comment: @Dan: redefining \bibitemNoStop as you suggests works for the particular endnote I'm having trouble with. But it also deletes the periods after all the references.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Grouping the \renewcommand with the footnote doesn't do the job, and (you probably know this already) grouping it inside the footnote is worse. Sigh.

Comment: I can get what I want by editing the bbl file: `\renewcommand{\bibitemNoStop}{}` just inside the bibitem I want to change, and `\renewcommand{\bibitemNoStop}{.}` just before the next bibitem. Of course I have to add `\nocontrols` to the preamble, and I'm not sure how all this will fly with the editor.

Comment: @ironphoton -- sigh indeed!  (i spaced through the fact that you're using endnotes.  although that may not make a difference.  didn't actually try it though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trick `revtex` into thinking a period is there:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,12pt,amsmath]{revtex4-1}
% I'm using the options aps, prl, and 12pt just to suppress
% some warnings; they do not affect the problem illustrated.

\newcommand\trick[1]{}

\begin{document}

This text includes an endnote that ends with an equation.%
~\footnote{%
  \unexpanded{\makeatletter\let\@bibitemShut\relax\makeatother}%
  Einstein derived the equation
  \[
    E = m c^2.
  \]\protect\trick.
}
And another footnote.~\footnote{What's that?}
\end{document}
```

But avoid displayed equations in footnotes.